# How to stop wordpress from mangling HTML in a metabox textarea

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, esc-textarea

Can anyone lend a hand and suggest the best way to get a textarea in a meta box to stop mangling HTML? I've been [digging around here online](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation)...  [and here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31811/html-javascript-in-custom-field-textarea)...[and also here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22190/how-do-i-stop-html-entities-in-a-custom-meta-box-from-being-un-htmlentitied)...looking for answers, but I don't know how to piece them together properly to fit with what I've already done.

Here's what I have...

```
add_action("admin_init", "tf_book_deets_create");

function tf_book_deets_create(){

    add_meta_box('tf_book_details', 'Book Details', 'tf_book_details', 'books');
}

function tf_book_details () {
    global $post;

    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);

    $tf_book_media = $custom["tf_book_media"][0];
    $tf_book_review = $custom["tf_book_review"][0];

    ?>

    <div class="admin_meta"> 
    <ul>

    <li><label>Reviews:</label><textarea rows="5" cols="70" name="tf_book_review" value="<?php echo $tf_book_review; ?>" ></textarea></li>

    <li><label>Media:</label><textarea rows="5" cols="70" name="tf_book_media" value="<?php echo $tf_book_media; ?>" ></textarea></li>
    </ul>

    </div>


<?php }

    add_action ('save_post', 'save_tf_book_details');   

    function save_tf_book_details(){ 
    global $post;

        update_post_meta($post->ID, "tf_book_media", $_POST["tf_book_media"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "tf_book_review", $_POST["tf_book_review"]);

    }
```

I'm just looking for some ideas.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'v re-worked your code.  I'll try to explain some of the changes after the code block

```
add_action("admin_menu", "tf_book_deets_create");

function tf_book_deets_create(){

    add_meta_box('tf_book_details', 'Book Details', 'tf_book_details', 'books');
}

function tf_book_details () {
    global $post;

    $tf_book_media = get_post_meta($post->ID, "tf_book_media", true);
    $tf_book_review = get_post_meta($post->ID, "tf_book_review", true);


    ?>

    <div class="admin_meta"> 
    <ul>

    <li><label>Reviews:</label><textarea rows="5" cols="70" name="tf_book_review"><?php echo esc_textarea($tf_book_review); ?></textarea></li>

    <li><label>Media:</label><textarea rows="5" cols="70" name="tf_book_media"><?php echo esc_textarea($tf_book_media); ?></textarea></li>
    </ul>

    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'book-nonce', 'book_nonce_name', false ); ?>

    </div>


<?php 
}

add_action ('save_post', 'save_tf_book_details');   


function save_tf_book_details( $post_id ) {

    // make sure we're on a supported post type
    if ( $_POST['post_type'] != 'books' ) return;  

    // verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization.
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['book_nonce_name'], 'book-nonce' )) return;

    // verify if this is an auto save routine. If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;


    // Check permissions
    if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) return;
    } else {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;
    }

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
    if ( isset( $_POST["tf_book_media"] ) ) update_post_meta( $post_id, "tf_book_media", wp_kses_post( $_POST["tf_book_media"] ) );
    if ( isset( $_POST["tf_book_review"] ) ) update_post_meta( $post_id, "tf_book_review", wp_kses_post( $_POST["tf_book_review"] ) );

}
```

**Textarea markup**

First I switched the textarea markup.  The value of a textarea is set in between the opening and closing textarea tags. The textarea's value is also escaped with [`esc_textarea()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_textarea)

**Basic sanitization and nonce security**

I added some basic validation and nonce security to the `save_tf_book_details()` function.  First the [`nonce`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) that I added to the metabox callback function is verified here, so we're sure the data is coming from the right place.

I also ran the text area inputs through the [`wp_kses_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses_post) function, which filters out any scripts or other tags that are not allowed in regular posts.

Comment: Thank you so much! Not only did this work (and save me a full night of my head on the desk), but its a good example to learn from for future builds. Appreciate your time, thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad it helped.  I just happened to be working on something very similar yesterday when you asked your question. Cheers.