# Data won't save on a straightforward metabox, what am I missing?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I need a second set of eyes, because its late and I can't see this anymore.

Why won't this save? What am I missing?

```
add_action("admin_menu", "tf_book_stuff_create");

function tf_book_stuff_create(){
    add_meta_box('tf_book_stuff', 'Book Stuff', 'tf_book_stuff', 'books');
}

function tf_book_stuff() {
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $tf_book_number = $custom["tf_book_number"][0];
    $tf_book_reader = $custom["tf_book_reader"][0];

    echo $tf_book_isbn;
    echo $tf_book_level;

?>  

    <div class="admin_meta"> 
    <ul>
        <li><label>Book ISBN:</label><input name="tf_book_number" value="<?php echo $tf_book_number; ?>" /></li>
        <li><label>Reading Level:</label><input name="tf_book_reader" value="<?php echo $tf_book_reader; ?>" /></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<?php }



add_action("admin_menu", "save_tf_book_stuff");
function save_tf_book_stuff($post_id) {
    global $post;

    update_post_meta($post->ID, "tf_book_number", $_POST["tf_book_number"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "tf_book_reader", $_POST["tf_book_reader"]);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65000/how-to-stop-wordpress-from-mangling-html-in-a-metabox-textarea/65006#65006 ?  Are you having further problems?

Comment: Kind of different, same vein. I usually have meta-box issues of some kind. Mostly I just forget something. In this case, one line.

Comment: Ok, but the code I provided there should have been saving properly. As I posted on your other question, $post_id is passed as a parameter to your `save_tf_book_stuff($post_id)` function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the global $post variable, try just using the `$post_id` that was passed to the function in the first place.

```
update_post_meta($post_id "tf_book_number", $_POST["tf_book_number"]);
update_post_meta($post_id, "tf_book_reader", $_POST["tf_book_reader"]);
```

Comment: Hmm. That didn't work. Maybe there's another way to code said meta box.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: S'okay, found a solution. Thank you for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found it. Its probably a little backwards (ie I'm sure there are shorter nicer ways to do it), but it works.

```
function save_tf_book_stuff() {
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
update_post_meta($post->ID, "tf_book_number", $_POST["tf_book_number"]);
update_post_meta($post->ID, "tf_book_reader", $_POST["tf_book_reader"]);
```

}